# Generating JAVA files and using them at runtime

Tags: java, testing, code-generation, testng

I'm trying the following, suggested by Cedric Beust in some other thread.

> You could do this yourself as a pre-test task: implement a code generator
>   that takes the information in XML form, grab the corresponding Java
>   source file and generate a TestNG source file with all the annotations
>   placed in the right locations. And then you run TestNG on that file.

I have no clue with code generation. Can someone guide me in the right direction? Some simple examples would be great.

Update: This is the template of what I would like to generate.

```
public class <tobeReadFromConfigFile>
{
  @Test(groups="to be read from config file")
  public void <tobereadfromconfigfile>{
     //to be read from config file(Name of function to call)
     //to be read from config file(Name of function to call)
     //to be read from config file(Name of function to call)
  }
  .
  .
  .
}
```

The code inside function will be just function calls, which has to be read and copied exactly from config file.

Comment: Examples of what, code generation? Use any template engine, like [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/), and fill it with Java code plus whatever dynamic stuff you need injected.

Comment: @DaveNewton- Yes, code generation examples apt for the above reason.

Comment: Not knowing anything about what you're trying to generate makes providing more specific assistance impossible. A template can be anything, including valid Java source. You can build, say, Java methods given external data, like from XML. You don't provide enough information to tell you much more other than "Use a template and your data to build legal Java code."

Comment: @DaveNewton- Added an example.

Comment: Moved to answer for space purposes. Just look at the FreeMarker docs to see how to use it, read in your data, build the context, and evaluate the template. You'll use essentially the same steps regardless of which library you pick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A FreeMarker template would look something like this:

```
public class ${className} {
    @Test(groups="${testGroups}")
    public void ${testMethodName}() {
        <#list methods as m>
        ${m}
        </#list>   
    }
}
```

It would be filled from a context, essentially a hashmap with `className`, `testGroups`, etc. entries, that would be read from your XML file. `methods` would be a `Collection` (like a list), also read from the XML file.

There are many other templating libraries, of course; this is just an example.

[FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/)

Comment: The config file can be anything(XML or JSON or anything), right? And then I'll use Fremarker which will read the config file and fill the template, right?

Comment: @questions You're the one loading the configuration file--it can be uuencoded Swahili written upside down as long as you can pull the data from it you need and convert it to something FreeMarker/etc. can handle. FreeMarker is a templating engine--*your code* digests the config info and sets up a context for the template. If you want to go straight from XML to Java with no code, use XSL (ew). You could also just use Groovy/JRuby/etc. to parse the XML and emit Java code.

Comment: Grreat.. Thanks. And does this looks like a good approach, I'll using the above generated classes with TestNG?

Comment: @questions You can use the generated code however you want--output from a template is arbitrary, as long as it does what you need it to, it can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

I have written an eclipse plugin that uses freemarker templates and provides the context of named java classes as ICompilationUnit from org.eclipse.jdt.core. You can check it out at https://github.com/karajdaar/templator