# I want to create java class dynamically by just passing particular parameters

Tags: java, testng

I am developing framework for API Testing,which uses TestNG.Right now i am having one class as ->

```
public class PostTest
{
    @Test(dataProvider="create_post")
     public void addPost(parameters from data provider)
     {
         // Code to add post  
     }
    @Test(dataProvider="get_post")
     public void getPost(parameter from data provider,In this case it could be id)
     {
         // Code to get post
     }
    @Test(dataProver="delete_post")
     public void deletePost(parameter from data provider,In this case it could be id)
     {
         // Code to delete post 
     }
}
```

As My project(of course maven based) directory structure is

> src->test->PostTest.java

Now I want to add one more new test for testing comments API.
So I need to write on new file with all this methods.I want another new class file for comments like CommentTest.java file under

> src->test->CommentTest.java

But I don't want to write whole new file and again edit all the api name from post to channel.So i want to dynamically create new class and edit these fields.For Eg.

```
 public class $(Dynamic)Test
{
    @Test(dataProvider="create_$(Dynamic)")
     public void add$(Dynamic)(parameters from data provider)
     {
         // Code to add $(Dynamic)  
     }
    @Test(dataProvider="get_$(Dynamic)")
     public void get$(Dynamic)(parameter from data provider,In this case it could be id)
     {
         // Code to get $(Dynamic)
     }
    @Test(dataProver="delete_$(Dynamic)")
     public void delete$(Dynamic)(parameter from data provider,In this case it could be id)
     {
         // Code to delete $(Dynamic) 
     }
}
```

Is there any way so I can simply pass parameter as name of API,and then automatic class should be get created under **src->test** directory and field $(Dynamic should get replaced by API name)

Comment: I think you should use your IDE templates. For intelliJ [see this](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/live-templates.html), for eclipse [see this](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fconcept-editor-templates.htm&cp=1_2_6)

Comment: @RC-can you please give me more info.

Comment: Let's suppose that you have such tool. But you still have to fill the methods body. How are you going to do this?

Comment: If you need just text .java files based on such a template, maybe something like [freemarker](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11041222/995891) would do? The template looks close to what you got.